# Parsing datetime to specifed datetime format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, datetime

Here i m trying to convert date to system specific format but tryparse exact is not working is not able to convert date to specified dateformat can anyone let me know how to achieve this!

```
public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labl.Text = Form1("12/05/2017");
    }
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private string Form1(string date)
{
    // Get the Current System culture.
    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;

    string[] SystemDateTimePatterns = new string[250];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string name in dtfi.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d'))
    {
        SystemDateTimePatterns[i] = name;
        i++;
    }
    string date1 = "asd";
    string[] myDateTimeFormat = { "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-dd-MM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
    foreach (string dateFormat in myDateTimeFormat)
    {
        if (dateFormat == (SystemDateTimePatterns[0]))
        {
            SqlParameter StartingDateParam;
            DateTime mdate;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, dateFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out mdate))
            {
                StartingDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                StartingDateParam.Value = mdate;
                date1 = StartingDateParam.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
    return date1;
}
}
```

Comment: You simply want to parse `12/05/2017` to a date? Why so much code? Is that `month/day/year` or `day/month/year`?

Comment: TryParseExact has an overload that takes an array of formats. All this code is not necessary

Comment: @jamiec its dd/MM/yyyy and so much code because convert.toDatetime or tryParse is not working on production side that's why i m doing this

Comment: @steve if i pass the array then tryParse won't come to know which format to take dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy. It takes the format in sequence

Comment: And how do you want to translate that string used by your question? 12/05/2017?

Comment: thats what i am asking is there any other method which will convert any date to the format which i m specifing

Answer (score 0):

You're code is an order of magnitude more complex than it needs to be. Your input is `12/05/2017` and you stated this is `day/month/year` format:

```
var input = "12/05/2017`;
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(input,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OSFV37546

Comment: here you know the format thats why you are able to specify the exact format but at runtime or in production you wont know which format it is and hence it will fail

Comment: @abhishek if you dont know what the format is then you have bigger problems - your example input is the perfect example of an ambiguous date. You *must* know the input and the expected format.At very least you need to pick one to try first.

Comment: but i know the system format so based on that can i convert any input date ?

Comment: Can you ensure the string is in the "system format"? If so, then just use that. I don;t get the problem. If the user is typing this in (eg) a webpage, you cant assume they'll type it exactly as you want it